# Problem trying to crop image using GeoJson, Python and rasterio

Tags: python, geojson, crop, gdal, rasterio

I'm trying to crop a piece of image from a satellite picture using rasterio, json, GeoJson and Python. But I'm facing the following issue. Does anyone has an idea how to solve it?

CODE

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.mask import mask
import json

#opens json file
myGeoms_file = open('floripa.json')
myGeoms_json = json.load(myGeoms_file)
myGeoms_file.close()

#parsing my json to a format appropriate for rasterio
coords = myGeoms_json['coordinates'][0]
parsedJson = [{
    'type': 'Polygon', 
    'coordinates': [[]]
}]
for i in coords:
  newCoord = (i[0],i[1])
  parsedJson[0]['coordinates'][0].append(newCoord)

#starting to image cropping process
with rasterio.open("CB04.tif") as src:
    out_image, out_transform = mask(src, parsedJson, crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta.copy()
```

**Issue**:

```
[{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-48.52309226989746, -27.596847566108902), (-48.52386474609375, -27.59707576282468), (-48.526482582092285, -27.60110715979902), (-48.52652549743652, -27.601943846249203), (-48.52382183074951, -27.604453867271626), (-48.52249145507812, -27.604263716176668), (-48.52184772491455, -27.604453867271626), (-48.51961612701416, -27.607001860107363), (-48.516783714294434, -27.60441583707903), (-48.51738452911376, -27.602248094283674), (-48.51674079895019, -27.599890149923038), (-48.51515293121338, -27.594717707186042), (-48.515281677246094, -27.594033100886566), (-48.51575374603271, -27.593995067077895), (-48.51644039154053, -27.59418523598927), (-48.52038860321045, -27.59791248005127), (-48.52163314819336, -27.597532154830994), (-48.52309226989746, -27.596847566108902)]]}]
```

---

```
WindowError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasterio/mask.py in raster_geometry_mask(dataset, shapes, all_touched, invert, crop, pad, pad_width)
     83         window = geometry_window(dataset, shapes, north_up=north_up, rotated=rotated,
---> 84                                  pad_x=pad_x, pad_y=pad_y)
     85 

6 frames
WindowError: windows do not intersect
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasterio/mask.py in raster_geometry_mask(dataset, shapes, all_touched, invert, crop, pad, pad_width)
     88         # depending on value of crop
     89         if crop:
---> 90             raise ValueError('Input shapes do not overlap raster.')
     91         else:
     92             warnings.warn('shapes are outside bounds of raster. '

ValueError: Input shapes do not overlap raster.
```

Comment: Are the raster and polygon in the same projection?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically creating the mask version of the raster file, Do the following for your solution:

```
#import rioxarray module
import rioxarray
from rasterio.crs import CRS

#open the geojson file with fiona
    with fiona.open("floripa.geojson", "r") as geojson:
      #create features
      features = [feature["geometry"] for feature in geojson]

    #open raster file with rasterio
    with rasterio.open("CB04.tif") as src:
        #clip the raster with polygon
        out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, features, crop=True)
        #copy meta data of the src
        out_meta = src.meta.copy()
```

See more information about reprojecting the raster file for in case if it requires you to match the crs

1. Open your .tif file in the following way:

   raster_file = rioxarray.open_rasterio("CB04.tif", masked=True).squeeze()
2. Check your crs for any mismatch

   print(raster_file.rio.crs)
   #prints the crs in a format: EPSG:32636
3. Open the geojson file and check the crs

   data = gpd.read_file("crops.geojson")
   print(data.crs)
   #prints the crs: EPSG:XXXXXX

There will be a mismatch, if you want to match them reproject the raster file CB04.tif

```
#open raster file ("CB04.tif") using rioxaarray

    raster_file = rioxarray.open_rasterio("CB04.tif", masked=True).squeeze()
```

#create the crs object, make dst_crs = EPSG you want to change
#eg. "EPSG:4326" if data.crs = EPSG:4326

```
    crs_wgs84 = CRS.from_string("EPSG:4326")
    raster_file = raster_file.rio.set_crs(crs_wgs84) 
#check the crs of your raster file:
print(raster_file.crs)
#prints EPSG:4326
```